# Rotate annotations with PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, annotations, rotation, pypdf

Is there a way to rotate the annotations created with the AnnotationBuilder?

I add annotations to pdf kitchen layouts,

It looks like the layouts were made with the axis rotated, since no matter in which orientation I set the layouts before running the code, afterwards the annotations created are always 90 degrees rotated clockwise relative to my drawing orientation.

With the acrobat javascript console I can do this right but I don't know how to run the code for many pdf inside a directory

The other solution would be to rotate the content of the drawing without rotating the page but that seems more difficult

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It sounds like the code for adding annotations doesn’t behave as you expect when the file contains pages with non-zero viewing rotations. Try preprocessing the PDF with `cpdf -upright in.pdf -o out.pdf`. This will leave the file visually unchanged by rotating the page content and counterotating the dimensions to compensate.

Comment: Thanks John, I tried adding pycpdflib to do that but was not able to load a file or dlls I'm a begginer, I'll keep trying.
 @johnwhitington

Comment: You can use the command line version of cpdf, by calling out to it from Python. Not as neat as pycpdflib, but it would work.